# Installing *.dmg via CLI

Tags: applications, install, command-line, dmg, package-management

How are *.dmg packages installed via the command line?
I noticed that they can be mounted with:

```
me@MacBook-Pro:~$ open /Users/me/Downloads/installer.dmg
```

What's next?

Comment: As long as you do not want to specify another destination and your software is in pkg format, you go:

`sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/DMGNAME/PKGNAME  -target /`

Be careful: if your software requires a reboot afterwards, the installer will not automatically do this. You have to do it on your own. (Reference: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030614230204397)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the diskimage contains a package or packages, you would list the packages on the mounted filesystem and then use `/usr/sbin/installer`

Answer (score -1):

After mounting, you need to cd /Volumes/xyz (where xyz is the mounted volume)

Comment: And then do what to install the software?

Comment: @patrix yep. You should use "hdiutil mount diskimage.dmg" instead of the open command